# Contacts menu is not accessible in Android 6

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, contacts

I want to restore contacts from Sim - I have gone to the dialer and then contacts, then I look for the menu button that should appear in the search bar (as described here: http://teckfront.com/import-contacts-sim-card-android-6-0-1-marshmallow-2/ )

However, the menu is not accessible.  All that appears there is the google microphone; when I tap it, it opens the microphone and invites me to say the name of a contact.

How do I access the contacts menu with the microphone in the way?  Alternatively, is there another way to transfer contacts from the SIM that I have not seen?

Comment: The menu has probably been edited by the manufacturer. Try the same thing in the contacts app under settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found the "menu" while connecting the phone to the PC. The dedicated application that self-installed from the phone allowed me to browse / move all media files and, of course, contacts from SIM card. Found it by chance...

Comment: This sounds like it would only work for a specific device or manufacturer, as not all phones come with such self-installing PC apps or allow SIM contacts to be restored from them.